# Use Angular 2 Services to pass global variables?

Tags: angular

In our NG starter boilerplate **app.component.ts** I have this code:

`export class AppComponent {title = "Website Title"}`

In the appropriate **app.component.html**, `title` will be included as follows:

`<p>{{title}}</p>`

But I would like to include this `title` variable globally. Let's say my structure was as follows:

`app.component.html
 app.component.ts
 test.component.html
 test.component.ts`

In **test.component.html** I would like to display the same information.

`<p>The title of this website is {{title}}</p>`

And the value of `{{title}}` would be derived from my **app.component.ts**. How would I use services to pass something like a string? Would it be worth passing in a directive instead? Something like:

`<p>The title of this website is <app-test></app-test></p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is necessary to use global variables, which are available in entire application structure, you can use **shared service**, which you have to place in **shared module**.

You can read about shared module here:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module

This kind of service class could looks like this (public variable in this example):

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
      globalVariable = "default";
}
```

In fact, I think it is not a good idea to have something like this in any app.

Comment: Thanks. Why would this be a bad idea?

Comment: In above example you could see that variable is public. It is not a good practice, because data is not immutable and you can change the value for example by mistake :)

Comment: @abrahamlinkedin, the `@Injectable()` decorator is not necessary if you are not injecting anything in this services's constructor.

Comment: It is recommend to add @Injectable() to every service class,